# How can I generate a guid and assign it to a variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateState : MonoBehaviour, IStateQuery
{
    private State m_state = new State();
    private Guid guidID;

    private void Awake()
    {
        guidID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid UniqueId => Guid.Parse(guidID.ToString());

    private class State
    {
        // Properties
    }

    public string GetState()
    {
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(m_state);
    }

    public void SetState(string jsonString)
    {
        m_state = JsonUtility.FromJson<State>(jsonString);
    }
}
```

It does generate a guid inside the Awake but I want to assign the guid after it created to the UniqueId variable at line 16 :

```
public Guid UniqueId => Guid.Parse(guidID.ToString());
```

but it's never getting to it. I'm using the UniqueID also in other scripts that's why I used =>

Comment: `UniqueId` isn't a variable, it's a property. And `Guid.Parse(guidID.ToString());` is utterly redundant. Just do `public Guid UniqueId { get; }` and assign it in your constructor. You don't need the `guidID` field.

Comment: @mjwills That's not valid C#.

Comment: `public Guid UniqueId {get;set;} = Guid.NewGuid();`

Answer (score 3):

> I want to assign the guid after it created to the UniqueId variable

You mean this?

```
public class GenerateState : MonoBehaviour, IStateQuery
{
    /*
     other implementation 
    */

    private Guid myGuid;
    
    public Guid UniqueId => myGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

Comment: Why have a field _and_ a property?

Comment: @mjwills: I think it is requirement, is it right? "assign the guid after it created to the UniqueId variable".

Comment: You could have the property with private setter.